# Filter posts before loading

Tags: javascript

How can i filter posts and get author:Mike posts for BlogScreen.

```
const BlogScreen = ({ data }) => {
  if (!data) {
    return (<Spinner />);
  }
  const { blog, author, posts } = data;
  return (
    <main>
      <BlogHeader name={blog.name} description={blog.description} />
      <div className={styles.posts}>
        {posts.map((post) => (
            <PostPreview post={post} author={author} key={post.id} />))}
      </div>
    </main>)};
```

Comment: I dont know what kind of db? You pass data via react component props and the props data is must be only about Mike. I think your problem is your query

Answer (score 2):

Selecting particular items from database is not frontend's responsibility. You should have an endpoint in your backend that takes authorName as parameter and returns blogPosts of that author. Then, you only pass the data of the author you want to BlogScreen component. You can not load all the blogpost in the database and do filtering in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const BlogScreen = ({ data, approvedAuthor }) => {
      if (!data) {
        return (<Spinner />);
      }
    
      if (data.author !== approvedAuthor) return null;
    
      const { blog, author, posts } = data;
    
      return (
        <main>
          <BlogHeader name={blog.name} description={blog.description} />
          <PreContent />
          <div className={styles.posts}>
            {
              posts.map((post) => (
                <PostPreview post={post} author={author} key={post.id} />
              ))
            }
          </div>
          <Footing />
        </main>
      );
    };    
  

  BlogScreen.defaultProps = {
    data: null,
    approvedAuthor: 'Mike',
  };
    
  BlogScreen.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object
    approvedAuthor: PropTypes.string,
  };
```

Comment: Hi, please add an explanation to the code in your answer.

Comment: @SomoKRoceS as I understand you mapped something with returned `BlogScreen` e.g. `data.map(item => ({ < BlogScreen data={item.data} />
}))`
I suggest to pass author as second prop e.g.
`data.map(item => ({
   < BlogScreen data={item.data} approvedAuthor={'Mike or whoever'} />
}))`